# python create json from loop

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am an python newbie trying to create data in json by iterating a for loop like `{region1: title1, region2:title2}`

Logic:

```
import json
for region in ["region1","region2","region3"]:
  title="logic to get the title in region"
  data = {region: title}
  # like to update_json.update(data) from second run
```

I would like the data to be appended with region:title for each loop run. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your goal here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json.dumps(dict)`:

```
import json

dic = {}
for region in ["region1","region2","region3"]:
    title="logic to get the title in region"
    dic[region] = title
j = json.dumps(dic)  # here is
```

Comment: Thank you. I have used the logic from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673952/json-generating-a-json-in-a-loop-in-python and it worked. Thank you